# Plot correlation values corresponding to a transformed meshgrided (X,Y) coordinates

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matrix 3x121 that contains (x,y, correlation value), 
First, I do a meshgrid of (x,y), then a transformation of (x,y) meshgrided into new coordinates (x',y') with x'=y/x and y'=1/x^2*y.

I have to plot the correlation according to the new coordinates (x',y') showed in the attached screen shot.
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bboU.jpg "correlation"

Here is the code that I used:

```
load('correlation_xy_0.mat');
x = double(corr_xy(1,:,:));
y = double(corr_xy(2,:,:));
correlation = double(corr_xy(3,:,:));

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Xp = Y./X;
Yp = 1./(X.^2 .*Y);

plot(Xp,Yp,'Color',correlation)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a colormap and provide RBG values. You also need to do this for each point independently, you can not do it in one line

```
cmap=parula; % choose a colormap
correlation=reshape(correlation,size(X));
hold on
for ii=1:size(x,1)
    for jj=1:size(x,1)
    plot(Xp(ii,jj),Yp(ii,jj),'x','color',cmap(floor(correlation(ii,jj)*size(cmap,1)+1),:)  )
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I get the following error :
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: `cmap(floor(correlation(ii,jj)*size(cmap,1)+1),:)` does not work because my correlation values are stored in a 1x121 vector

Comment: Any ideas please ?

Comment: Thank you @Ander, I get another error when using reshape :
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
because correlation is 1x121 array and X is a 121x121 matrix
thank you

Comment: @amine thats on you though. I suspect you are creating too many `x` and `y`. But if your description is right, you have 1 correlation value per point. Of course it would be considerably easier to help with a [mcve]